# cppcms - Shared library - Linux

Tags: linux, debian, shared-libraries, cppcms

I am trying to use the cppcms framework on Linux(Debian distribution).

I followed the steps described in the Build tutorial on the site and then tried to build the hello world application.

I have successfully compiled the source, but when I try to run it I get the following error:

./hello: error while loading shared libraries: libcppcms.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I am relatively new to Linux so I had to a little research and come across these things called Shared Libraries. As I understood, these *.so files are exactly what I was needing to create. 
I also read that the base folder for libraries was /home/usr/lib so I tried copying the file onto that folder, but it didn't help.

I would really appreciate any help that might get me through this problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I was able to recover from this problem by executing "sudo ldconfig"

Answer (score 2):

Also this worked out for me:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/library/
./hello -c config.js
```

where "/path/to/library/" is the actual directory where libcppcms.so.1
lives. (mine was /usr/local/lib/)

[got it from http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.cppcms.user/764 ]

Answer (score 1):

1. Instead of building CppCMS on your own, install ready to use deb: http://cppcms.com/wikipp/en/page/apt#Apt-Get.Repositories
2. You can use the troubleshooting guide that the problem you are talking about was mentioned: http://cppcms.com/wikipp/en/page/cppcms_1x_build_troubleshooting#My.sample.application.does.not.find.the.shared.object..code.libcppcms.so..code..when.I.try.to.run.it.